# Update feature class from values in csv file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I'm trying to update a feature class with new data from a csv file. My workflow is as follows:

1. Make a csv reader from csv file
2. Identify my data columns using their index position
3. Use an update cursor to update the values in the shapefile with data from the csv

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv
import arcpy
csvfile = "C:\\Data\\data.csv"
shpfile = "C:\\Data\\TEST.gdb\\azcounties"
file = open(csvfile,"r")
csvReader = csv.reader(file)
header = csvReader.next()
nameIndex = header.index("NAME")
dateIndex = header.index("DATE")
valueIndex = header.index("VALUE")
dateField = "DATE"
nameField = "NAME_2"
valueField = "VALUE"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shpfile,(nameField,dateField,valueField)) as cursor:
 for row in cursor:
     for rw in csvReader:
         row[0] = rw[nameIndex]
         row[1] = rw[dateIndex]
         row[2] = rw[valueIndex]
         cursor.updateRow(row)
```

It seems to almost work. I don't get any errors, but only the first row in the shapefile gets updated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The inner loop (`rw in csvReader`) is just going to replace the value of every row in the outer loop with the last record of the `csvReader`.  Plus, you're calling `updateRow` on every loop of the `csvReader` which is a slow down and doesn't fully make sense.

Comment: I'm trying to loop through a csv file with 3 columns and 15 rows and update the corresponding fields in a shapefile. Each iteration I'm trying to pull the current row from the csv file and update the current row in the shapefile.

Comment: So the feature class record 1 needs information from the 1st row in the CSV?  Are there unique identifiers so you could just do a join and save the data that way?

Comment: Yes, feature class row 1 gets data from csv row 1. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Doing a join could work but then I have to strip off old fields, and may not always have common field.

Comment: Your other option would be to try to match one row of one file to the same indexed row of another like your script (I believe) wanted to accomplish.. that is pretty tedious though and you'd have to worry about sorting order changing, etc.  It is probably better and easier to just deal with the potential problems of joins.  No fields, create them.  Extra fields, delete them (or disable before join/export).  Those seem easier.

Comment: Cool, well I'll try the join. But is it possible to simultaneously iterate through the cursor rows and the csvreader, populating the fields like I was trying to do?

Comment: Simultaneously.. No, not really.  It'd be more like iterating over one and pulling the row index out of the other on each iteration.  If you really wanna do it, it can be coded, but it isn't really a better solution than joining.